# Drupal 7 - How can I add a region inside another region?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm surprised I can't find the answer to this online.

I'm currently creating a custom header for my drupal site, so I've created a custom_header region in the .info and a region--custom-header.tpl.php file. Inside the region, I need to add another region.

I've tried to print the other region inside the header region by using - `<?php print render($page['regionname']); ?>`, but nothing is showing up.

Good practise or not aside, how can I do this?

Comment: Without coding: Maybe you want to have a look at [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Answer (score 1):

`$page` isn't available in region.tpl.php files (in node.tpl.php, for example, it's available, but only as a flag for the full page state, not as an array with regions' information).

To get access for any region in region.tpl.php, you should create new variable via a preprocess function.

Add to your template.php file:

```
function youtheme_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  $variables['regionname'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('regionname');
}
```

And then you can output content from this region like that:

```
echo render($regionname);
```